# correctness of forward oriented optimistic concurrency control

Tags: database, concurrency, optimistic-concurrency

I'm learning OCC in databases, the forward-oriented OCC algorithm needs a transaction to validate all transactions that run in parallel, but are still in their read phase. I'm confused why it can ensure commit order-preserving serializability (COCSR, which means the equivalent serialized order is identical to the commit order).

Actually, I can give a counterexample like this:

```
tx1: |--r(x)---|--validation--|------w(y)----|
tx2:          |----r(z)----------r(y)----------|
```

The validation of `tx1` will pass because in its validation phase it doesn't see the `r(y)` of `tx2`. `tx2` is a read-only transaction so it doesn't need validation phase. (The algorithm is from the book "Transactional Information Systems")

However, `tx1` commits before `tx2` but `tx2` doesn't see the value which `tx1` writes. That contradicts with the definition of COCSR, why?

Answer (score 1):

The validation-write phase is a critical section. When a thread is in val-write phase, no other thread can do any read/write operation.

> tx1: |--r(x)---(--validation---w(y)-)----|
>
> tx2:          |----r(z)------------------------------r(y)-------|

Answer (score 0):

Validation doesn’t actually have to be in a critical section, as long as it occurs after all write locks and the commit timestamp have been acquired. Then, as long as readers wait on write locks, we know that no item in our write set can be added to the read set of any active txn after validation begins, so validation is non-racy. Provided we also maintain the invariant that no txn can publish its commit decision while any validating txn with a lower commit timestamp remains undecided, we can abort any concurrent conflicting txn during validation, either while it is still in its read phase, or after it has entered its validation phase (while it is waiting for our txn to commit). No critical section is required.